# What exactly is sent when a RESTful request is sent. How is the information in the METHOD and BODY sent to the URL?

Tags: rest

trying to understand more about RestFul calls.  I understand the format, but what I want to know is how the call is actually sent.  For example, if I were to setup Fiddler on my client, and I were to make a RestFul call to http:/thisplace.com/rws with Method = POST and Body = Login HTTP/1.1
Host: client.mydomain.com
Accept: application/xml
Content-type: application/xml

What exactly do I see being sent out from the client on fiddler?  Is the information coded inside the URL?

Wondering if RestFul calls can be sent without a third-party tool such as PostMan.

Answer (score 1):

RestFul services use standard HTTP methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc). The parameters in a HTTP POST request are sent in the request body which appears after the headers. The information/parameters are not encoded in the URL in a POST request.

The format that the parameters are sent depends on the Content-Type of the request.

In your example you specify `content-type: application/xml` which means you'd need to provide xml in the request body.  In fiddler an HTTP POST to http://thisplace.com/rws might look something like this (for `application/xml`):

```
POST http://thisplace.com/rws HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
Host: thisplace.com
content-length: 64

<myData>
    <value>hello</value>
    <value2>world</value2>
</myData>
```

The request body is below the headers and is the after the blank line where you see the xml.

If you specified `application/json` the parameters would be encoded as json, and the request body might look like:

```
{ 
    "value1": "hello", 
    "value2": "world" 
}
```

For content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the parameters would be in the same format as a query string and the request body might look like:

```
value1=hello&value2=world
```

Yes, RestFul calls can be  made without postman but you haven't specified which language/technology you're using or how you'd like to send the requests.